# Docker + Spring Boot/MVC WAR = Tomcat 404

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, dockerfile, war

so I am trying to dockerize my Spring Boot web app. Under IntelliJ it works fine, but as soon as I deploy it - the http status 404 appears instead of my homepage.

**project structure**

```
-src
   -main
      -java
         ...my packages
      -resources
         ...application.properties and others
      -webapp
         -WEB-INF
            -views
               ...jsp pages
         -resources
            ...js, css, images
   -test
```

The **pom.xml** includes spring-boot-starter dependencies, Tomcat and spring-boot-maven plugin.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.51-jre8-alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY ./target/charity-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
```

I think somehow the Docker doesn't see the WEB-INF folder. I'm in trouble with this for over 2 days... Any ideas?
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm, you are doing

> ```
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>    <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

and mark the packaging as a war in **pom.xml**

Also, you need to modify the main class of your application

Please take reference from below link
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record - this Dockerfile finally worked:

```
FROM java:8
ADD /target/charity-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war charity.war
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/charity.war"]
```